# Microsoft ui-automation not able to fetch chrome's context menu elements

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, microsoft-ui-automation

Why UIAutomation is not able to fetch chrome's context menu elements.

**C# Code:**
The below code will subscribe to the root element.

```
 public void SubscribeToInvoke()
        {
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent,
                    AutomationElement.RootElement,
                    TreeScope.Descendants, UIAEventHandler);

            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuClosedEvent,
                    AutomationElement.RootElement,
                    TreeScope.Descendants, UIAEventHandler);
        }
```

The bellow event is not getting fired in the case of google chrome, but in other cases (i.e. IE or Firefox or any other application) it is fine.

```
        private void UIAEventHandler(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
        {
            AutomationElement sourceElement;
            sourceElement = sender as AutomationElement;
            if (e.EventId == AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent)
            {
            }
            else if (e.EventId == AutomationElement.MenuClosedEvent)
            {
            }
        }
```

Is there any code changes required or is there any alternative solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this task by using a method called as FromPoint(). My use case was to get right click and paste event.

Step 1: Subscribe to the menu open and close event:

```
public void SubscribeToInvoke()
        {
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent,
                    AutomationElement.RootElement,
                    TreeScope.Descendants, UIAEventHandler);

Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuClosedEvent,
                    AutomationElement.RootElement,
                    TreeScope.Descendants, UIAEventHandler);
        }
```

Step 2: When MenuOpenedEvent start timer which will get the current location of your mouse and on MenuCloseEvent strop timer.

```
if (e.EventId == AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent)
            {
                timer_Chrome.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (e.EventId == AutomationElement.MenuClosedEvent)
            {
                timer_Chrome.Enabled = false;
             }
```

Step 3: Get the element at the mouse location

```
            System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
            AutomationElement sourceElement = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
```